# Adding compiler "#define" flags in sub_directory CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

My directory structure of project is build with multi CMakeLists.txts.

- root

  - CMakeLists.txt
  - Src

    - main.c
  - CMSIS_lib

    - calculate.c
    - calculate.h
    - CMakeLists.txt
  - cmake

    - toolchain.cmake
  - build

In my CMSIS_lib I build separately my dependency source files `calculate.c`
 and `calculate.h` with **CMSIS_lib/CMakeList.txt**:

```
set(util_source_files
  calculate.c
  calculate.h
)
add_library(util ${util_source_files})
target_include_directories(util calculate.h)
```

In my root **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(main_projct)
set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX /opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE cmake/toolchain.cmake)

add_subdirectory(CMSIS_lib)

add_executable(main_projct main.c)
target_link_libraries(main_projct util)
```

Problem is that I must tell my compiler to add a `#define GUCCI` in my `calculate.h` (In MakeFile I know there is flag to tell a header define with `-DGUCCI`). I would like to add this flag to my compiler in my **CMSIS_lib/CMakeList.txt**, because when the first CMSIS_lib/CMakeList.txt is done building, he will skip everything under `#ifndef GUCCI` in my `calculate.h`, and when added in root CMakeLists.txt with `target_link_libraries()` I will not have all defines configuration correctly.

I am using cross-compiler and in my `toolchain.cmake` I use to define compiler flags with command `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${TARGET} PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS GUCCI}")`, but this is to late because this only is seen by my root CMakeLists.txt and not by my sub director CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CMSIS_lib/CMakeLists.txt` should look like this:

```
set(util_source_files
    calculate.c
    calculate.h
)

add_library(util ${util_source_files})
target_include_directories(util ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_compile_definitions(util PUBLIC GUCCI)
```

Note *target_compile_definitions* line, with PUBLIC parameter: it instructs cmake to use `-DGUCCI` compiler option while compiling util, and all targets that are linked against util.

Also note change in target_include_directories. You placed header file as parameter, but you should place directory instead.

Comment: Answer is correct, but there is a typo in "target_compile_definitions" one "i" is missing in "difinitions". Thank you <3